# How to assign only one value to the zeroth index of an array and that all in that array, in java

Tags: java, android, arrays

```
if (uri.contains(",")) {
                more_than_one_url = uri.split(",");
            } else
                more_than_one_url[0] = uri;
for (String url : more_than_one_url) {/*operation*/}
```

Is it possible to do such operation with only one element in a String[] or is there any better way to do this, if I use different names for String and String[] then it becomes very difficult for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you check if your `String uri` contains a `,`? `split()` will return a `String[]` even if it does not find the regex you supplied. Instead of checking using `contains()`, simply do this.

```
String[] more_than_one_url = uri.split(",");
for (String url : more_than_one_url) {/*operation*/}
```

If it does not find the delimiter supplied, `split()` will return an array of length 1 which will contain the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to assign an array on one line, change

```
more_than_one_url[0] = uri;
```

to something like

```
more_than_one_url = new String[] { uri };
```